# How to change text color in a plot?

Tags: r, plot

Is there any function to change colors of selected text, so that I can display custom colors of text that display anywhere in a plot?

Just an example, if I'd like to change the font of "-Log10adjustedP", I can use `bquote`

```
bquote(~-Log[10] ~ adjusted~italic(P))
```

Is there a `color` equivalent to this?

Comment: I think with base graphics its kind of all or nothing. If using grid graphics, you can check out this newer package: https://wilkelab.org/gridtext/

Comment: @MrFlick Beware of the `phantom` ;)

Answer (score 3):

Using `phantom` which doesn't plot the text but leaves space for it. This allows us to do a layer-wise approach which is quite flexible.

```
plot(dnorm(seq(-5, 5, .01)), type="l")

text(0, .35, bquote(.("Lorem ")*phantom(.("ipsum"))), col=1, adj=0)
text(0, .35, bquote(phantom(.("Lorem "))*"ipsum"), col=2, adj=0)
text(0, .35, bquote(phantom(.("Lorem ipsum "))*"dolor"), col=3, adj=0)
text(0, .35, bquote(phantom(.("Lorem ipsum dolor "))*"sit "), col=4, adj=0)
text(0, .35, bquote(phantom(.("Lorem ipsum dolor sit "))*"amet."), col=5, adj=0)

text(650, .35, bquote(~-Log~phantom(.[10])~phantom(adjusted~italic(P))), col="#000000", adj=0)
text(650, .35, bquote(~phantom(-Log)[10]~phantom(adjusted~italic(P))), col="#ff0000", adj=0)
text(650, .35, bquote(~phantom(-Log[10])~adjusted~phantom(italic(P))), col="#00ff00", adj=0)
text(650, .35, bquote(~phantom(-Log[10]~adjusted)~italic(P)), col="#0000ff", adj=0)
```

Note, that if subsequent letters are longer upwards or downwards to the first un-`phantom`ed text, we better include a `phantom` of those, otherwise the characters get shifted:

```
text(75, .2, bquote("c"*phantom("ol")), col=1, adj=0, font=2, cex=1.5)
text(75, .2, bquote(phantom("c")*"o"*phantom("l")), col=2, adj=0, font=2, cex=1.5)
text(75, .2, bquote(phantom("co")*"l"), col=3, adj=0, font=2, cex=1.5)
text(75, .2, bquote(phantom("col")*"o"), col=4, adj=0, font=2, cex=1.5)
text(75, .2, bquote(phantom("colo")*"r"), col=5, adj=0, font=2, cex=1.5)
text(75, .2, bquote(phantom("color")*"f"), col=6, adj=0, font=2, cex=1.5)
text(75, .2, bquote(phantom("colorf")*"u"), col=7, adj=0, font=2, cex=1.5)
text(75, .2, bquote(phantom("colorfu")*"l"), col=8, adj=0, font=2, cex=1.5)
```

For the `title` there exists a convenience function `ContourFunctions::multicolor.title` which internally also uses `phantom`.

```
ContourFunctions::multicolor.title(c("This ","could ", "be ", "your ", "title"), 1:5)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

An alternative way is to use `mtext`.

```
plot(1:20)
mtext(~-Log[10] ~ adjusted~italic, col = "blue")
```

[image: a simple example of mtext with color]